# need small javascript for greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

HI, i need a greasemonkey code for a web page. The page has hidden input type and value. I need a gm script which can alert  the value of the hidden input object as soon as the page loads.

The input tag is present in a form with:

form id="bloog" method="post" action= "/newpage.php" name="bloog">

The hidden content is present as:

```
<input type="hidden" value="abcd" name="ans">
```

now as soon as the page loads the value abcd must come in the alertbox.. some body please help me i've been trying for these...

Comment: Please post the code you've written this far.

Comment: i dont have any code.. i want the script for website which is having hidden objects and no sooner the website loads the alert with hidden value i.e abcd must appear... i've just started testing on it....

Comment: This seems more like a request for working code than a question. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Script Name Here
// @namespace     http://www.yourdomain.com
// @description   An Greasemonkey script that hides alerts hidden field value
// @include       *
// ==/UserScript==

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].getAttribute("name") == "ans") {
    alert(inputs[i].getAttribute("value"));
  }
}
```

Read [Get Started With Greasemonkey](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_greasemonkey/) on WebMonkey

Comment: the code works as expected.. Instead of showing the value in alert box,can the script automatically select the radio button corresponding to that value... Thanks